# php statement causing "500 - Internal server error" when logged out

Tags: javascript, php

I have this function in index.php...

```
function getCurrentUserID(){
  var currentUserID;
  if (confirmLogin()){
    currentUserID = "<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user_id']); ?>";
  } else {
    currentUserID=-1;
  }
  return currentUserID;
}
```

When I'm logged in it works nicely and returns the user_id.  The second I log out (which refreshes index.php) I hit a "500 - Internal server error" that I can only resolve by DELETING the php line from the function (if I even comment out using javascripts // notation I still see the 500 error).  Once I've deleted the line I can then refresh the page, log back in, and if I want add php reference to the function again!

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this problem permanently though?  I don't know why the php script is problematic since it's inside a "confirmLogin()" check (not to the mention the fact it's sometimes commented out altogether!)  Feels like I might have put this in the wrong place but I really don't know what the right place is!  Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: If you log out you probably unset the session array. So try to check with isset if the value exists and on true only echo it

Comment: Your issue is likely that when not logged in, `$_SESSION` doesn't have an index of `user_id`. Try checking if isset before using an index in an array. `<?php echo isset($_SESSION['user_id'])?$_SESSION['user_id']:'';?>` or in your php code, if not isset, set a default value like 0 or ''.

Comment: It doesn't matter what "checks" you put the PHP inside, or how many JavaScript comments it's inside. Those aren't PHP comments so the code will get executed.

Comment: thanks for all the super fast and insightful help - based on these comments I fixed it with "<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){ echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user_id']);} ?>";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP code is being parsed server-side, so way before any JS comes to life - that's why it doesn't matter if your line is inside the JS function.

What causes your problem is fact you're trying to access an array element under the non-existing key. In PHP it is illegal. The quickest fix is to check, if the value is set before echoing it: `<?php isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? echo $_SESSION['user_id' : echo '-1'; ?>`

This will resolve your issue but, in general, I would try to avoid mixing programming languages like that.

Comment: thanks Hipolith - the issue is now fixed thanks to the help I received and I'll mark this as the accepted answer in a few mins!